# Communicating between two python files using unix pipe and filter (concurrently)

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, unix, file-io

I want to be able to start two concurrent processes in python from the terminal and have one's output fed to the next one's input.

I am trying the following code:

File 1:(f1.py)

```
while(1):
  sys.stdout.write("a");
```

File 2:(f2.py)

```
while(x=sys.stdin.readline()):
  print x
```

Running the files:

```
$ python f1.py | python f2.py
```

Problem is that the readline command blocks the reading program from running unless the writing one finishes. Is there a way to achieve concurrency??

Comment: Output buffering may be? Try doing a `sys.stdout.flush()` after `sys.stdout.write("a")`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but no, it still doesn't work. This pipe should be able to stream data, right?